# XML parsing as <?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>

Tags: php, xml, twilio

I built a Twilio app in Phpstorm and I'm uploading everything normal and the application is working just fine, but randomly, Twilio will throw errors that it had an issue parsing the xml and shows this in the error:

```
12100 Document parse failure
Error on line 1 of document  : The value following "version" in the XML declaration must be a quoted string.  Please ensure that the response body is a valid XML document.

<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>
<Response>
    <Redirect>NOCC.php</Redirect>
</Response>
```

So I checked on the server and the code is still correct

```
<?php

session_start();
require '../../../Services/phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';
include '../../../Services/session.php';

$callerid = $_REQUEST['From'];
$callsid=$_SESSION['callsid'];

$mail = new PHPMailer;

//$mail->SMTPDebug = 3;                               // Enable verbose debug output

$mail->isSMTP();              // Set mailer to use SMTP
$mail->Host = ''; // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
$mail->SMTPAuth = false;      // Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = '';         // SMTP username
$mail->Password = '';         // SMTP password
$mail->SMTPSecure = '';       // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
$mail->Port = ;           // TCP port to connect to

$mail->From = '';
$mail->FromName = '';
$mail->addAddress('');     // Add a recipient

$mail->addAttachment("../../../uploads/images/$callsid.png", "$callsid.png");    // Optional name
$mail->addEmbeddedImage("../../../uploads/images/$callsid.png", "$callsid.png");    // Optional name
$mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML

$mail->Subject = "$site_name | ARM | $title | $first_name | $last_name | $account_number | FAILED PIN AUTH";
$mail->Body = "<img src='uploads/images/$callsid.png' />";
$mail->AltBody = "<img src='uploads/images/$callsid.png' />";

header('content-type: text/xml');
echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>';
echo '<Response>';

if(!$mail->send()) {
echo '<Redirect>alarm.php</Redirect>';
} else {

echo '<Redirect>NOCC.php</Redirect>';
}
echo '</Response>';
```

Any suggestions why it would be throwing the error sometimes?

Comment: That line looks fine, it is just shown escaped. The error is something else. With that little information given it is hard to help. But what clearly strikes here is that certainly is no valid xml. Where is the closing tag for the `response` element? And where is the closing curly bracket of the `else` case? Also the content type header is defined with camel case: `Content-Type`, not `content-type`. You also have to make sure nothing "bubbles" out of your script when something is odd in the mail sending routines. Like warnings displayed in the output, corrupting the xml...

Comment: Is this your entire code? You seem to be missing closing tags and closing brackets. Can you update with the entire code? Your XML is invalid right now

Comment: Sorry, edited with full code posted

Comment: @arkascha : The error mesage says `The value following "version" in the XML declaration must be a quoted string` and since it would be just a quoted string if there were no backslashes, the escaping might still be the cause of the error.

Comment: That `echo` command with the xml declaration is just fine. That is certainly not the issue. Except if you somehow have strange utf characters in there instead of correct quote chars. The escaping shown in the log file is just there to allow showing the quote chars in a log file. Just to be real sure: that error message is what you get in the http servers error log file? And the output of the script is sent where? Is it maybe processed somehow?

Comment: @arkascha I'm assuming it's processed by Twilios API, if that's what you mean. The call will go through the first ten pages just fine and even the last page most of the time. It's only sometimes it will throw this error and it's only on the last page. I'll check to make sure it's using the correct characters, but I don't see why it would be any different than the other pages, considering I did a find and replace across the whole app and I'm still randomly getting the error. And like I said, there are four different pages Twilio could end the call on, and it doesn't happen on all of them.

Comment: OK, you will have to dig deeper, probably the best approach is to dump requests either by logging them or by using a network sniffer. I bet this is some warning or similar you do not expect which contains some quote chars or similar.

Comment: @arkascha actually now that you mention it, I recall one of the times I was trying to do a find and replace, I pasted what I wanted to search inside Phpstorm and the quotes showed up just fine, but then when I hit search, it added an extra single quote on the outside of the quotes and said it couldn't find any matches. So I pasted "some text" and when I hit search it said it couldn't find any matches for '"some text"'